# UnusedBytecodeStripper2.exe did not run properly

Tags: unity-game-engine, il2cpp

I am trying make my iOS game to build for iOS. I set the scripting backend to IL2CPP (armv7 and arm64) and i am getting the following errors..

I use `MobileMoveScript Plugin 2.1.3` and `Mobile Social Plugin 6.6`. I don't think there is any problem with the plugins as i have tried build to them separately and it worked.

Failed running

> /Applications/Unity/Unity.app/Contents/Frameworks/Tools/UnusedByteCodeStripper2/UnusedBytecodeStripper2.exe
>   -out "/Users/abeltherock007/Documents/Unity Projects/Talking Superstar 2/Temp/StagingArea/Data/Managed" -l none -c link -x
>   "/Applications/Unity/Unity.app/Contents/Frameworks/Tools/UnusedByteCodeStripper/native_link.xml"
>   -f "/Applications/Unity/Unity.app/Contents/Frameworks/il2cpp/LinkerDescriptors"
>   -x "/Users/abeltherock007/Documents/Unity Projects/Talking Superstar 2/Temp/StagingArea/Data/Managed/../platform_native_link.xml" -x
>   "/Users/abeltherock007/Documents/Unity Projects/Talking Superstar
>   2/Temp/StagingArea/Data/methods_pointedto_by_uievents.xml" -x
>   "/Users/abeltherock007/Documents/Unity Projects/Talking Superstar
>   2/Assets/link.xml" -d "/Users/abeltherock007/Documents/Unity
>   Projects/Talking Superstar 2/Temp/StagingArea/Data/Managed" -a
>   "/Users/abeltherock007/Documents/Unity Projects/Talking Superstar
>   2/Temp/StagingArea/Data/Managed/Assembly-CSharp.dll" -a
>   "/Users/abeltherock007/Documents/Unity Projects/Talking Superstar
>   2/Temp/StagingArea/Data/Managed/UnityEngine.UI.dll"

> stdout; Fatal error in Mono CIL Linker
>   Mono.Cecil.AssemblyResolutionException: Failed to resolve assembly:
>   'U3DXTCore, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' at
>   Mono.Linker.LinkContext.Resolve (IMetadataScope scope) [0x00000] in
>   :0  at
>   Mono.Linker.Steps.ResolveFromXmlStep.GetAssembly
>   (Mono.Linker.LinkContext context, System.String assemblyName)
>   [0x00000] in :0  at
>   Mono.Linker.Steps.ResolveFromXmlStep.ProcessAssemblies
>   (Mono.Linker.LinkContext context, System.Xml.XPath.XPathNodeIterator
>   iterator) [0x00000] in :0  at
>   Mono.Linker.Steps.ResolveFromXmlStep.Process () [0x00000] in :0  at Mono.Linker.Steps.BaseStep.Process
>   (Mono.Linker.LinkContext context) [0x00000] in :0 
>   at Mono.Linker.Pipeline.Process (Mono.Linker.LinkContext context)
>   [0x00000] in :0  at Mono.Linker.Driver.Run ()
>   [0x00000] in :0  at Mono.Linker.Driver.RunDriver
>   (Mono.Linker.Driver driver) [0x00000] in :0  stderr:
>
> UnityEngine.Debug:LogError(Object)
>   UnityEditorInternal.Runner:RunManagedProgram(String, String, String,
>   CompilerOutputParserBase)
>   UnityEditorInternal.AssemblyStripper:RunAssemblyLinker(IEnumerable`1,
>   String&, String&, String, String)
>   UnityEditorInternal.AssemblyStripper:StripAssembliesTo(String, String,
>   String&, String&, String, String, IEnumerable`1)
>   UnityEditorInternal.AssemblyStripper:Strip(String, String, String&,
>   String&, String, String, IEnumerable`1)
>   UnityEditorInternal.AssemblyStripper:Strip(String[], String[], String,
>   String, String&, String&, String, String, IEnumerable`1)
>   UnityEditorInternal.IL2CPPBuilder:RunAssemblyStripper(IEnumerable,
>   String, String[], String[], String)
>   UnityEditorInternal.IL2CPPBuilder:StripAssemblies(String[], String)
>   UnityEditorInternal.IL2CPPBuilder:Run()
>   UnityEditorInternal.IL2CPPUtils:RunIl2Cpp(String, String,
>   IIl2CppPlatformProvider, Action`1, RuntimeClassRegistry)
>   UnityEditor.HostView:OnGUI()

Comment: What settings are you using for "Stripping Level" and "Api Compatibility" in the Player Settings? I've seen a few similar problems with U3DXTCore, and they usually depend upon these settings.

Answer (score 7):

I ran into the problem and didn't find anything online but I solved it at last.
The problem here is u3dxt plugin for iOS. it is not 64 bit compatible or atleast the version that I was using was not. So you have to have a work around for it.
I removed the plugin and it was all ok.
also note that even if you have removed the plugin and link file is still there in Asset/ folder, the problem will not be solved. so **remove plugin folder and u3dxt link file.**

Comment: I had removed u3dxt, but didn't remove the link.xml file. Your solution solved it for me too, thanks!

Comment: Where do I find the link.xml on a mac, any ideas?

Comment: @AhmetAkkök
It is in Assets/ folder of your project. you can also search the project for link.xml in unity. Make sure to delete only the file related to u3dxt plugin